# Symfony 6 does not work in a subdirectory on the server

Tags: symfony, deployment, symfony6

I need to run the application I wrote with symfony 6 in a subfolder. There will be 2 applications in the same domain. I defined virtual host in .htaccess file but it didn't work. I define rewrite base but it doesn't work. symfony detects the folder name as domain.com/folder route and says route not found.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /controlpanel/public

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
    RewriteRule ^/controlpanel/(.*)$ /controlpanel/index.php [QSA,L,PT]

    Alias /controlpanel /controlpanel/public

    <Directory /controlpanel/public>

      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can you provide an example htaccess where I can do this. Or will the directoryroot part of the virtual host be the directory where the project is located on the server? I'll be happy if you can help me. thanks

Comment: Please have a look to https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi

Comment: it does not work

Comment: I use a lot of apps with symfony, from 4 to 6, without any problems. All running on apache. 
Please, give some information about your configuration because the problem is how you configured apache. It's not related with symfony at all.

Comment: Apache is so flexible that makes things a little bit too much complicated sometimes. 
On windows I used to work with xampp to develop.
But I use Linux since 2016 and all that I do is: create a symlink to /var/www/html/myNewApp. As easy as that.

ln -s ~/Work/MySymfonyApp/public /var/www/html/MyApp

Then I browse for localhost/MyApp